# How to allow popup menu to go outside application window bounds in flutter desktop?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I don't even think this is possible but, what I'm looking for is to allow the `showMenu()` popup to go beyond the application window.

Currently, I'm using:

```
showMenu(
    context: context,
    items: <PopupMenuEntry>[
      PopupMenuItem(
        value: 1,
        child: Row(
          children: const <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.delete),
            Text("Delete"),
          ],
        ),
      )
    ], 
    position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0, 0,0,0),
);
```

Simply changing the position field to be below the height bounds of the application window doesn't work for me.

Edit: I do know that it is possible with a C# desktop app where a dropdown popup can go outside the bounds of the application window, so I figured flutter could do this as well.

Comment: Why do you want your popup to go outside of window?

Comment: Well truthfully, I'm trying to make a toolbar at the top that is height of 100, that when on hover or click of some icons, a dropdown that has options span downwards. Trying to save screen space. I guess I could just make the window borders transparent and the background transparent and increase the height of the application ?

Comment: Well trying what I said in the above comment, setting scaffolds background color to transparent renders a black background.

Comment: Scaffold provides us Material design with white background if you give it transparent then it will show it's parent background which is black.

Comment: You may be able to do your transparency idea by using the flutter_acrylic plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Flutter [only supports a single window](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30701), so there's no way to do this from Dart at the moment.

If it's a critical feature for your application, you would need to build a plugin that shows a native popup. The menu's UI would need to be native as well, unless you bring up a second Flutter engine just to draw it.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping, but figured this might be the case.